# Which value is used for verifiying Zip password?

Tags: encryption, crc

I am studying the way that can be used to check if a given password for an encrypted zip file is correct or not. I see this link:

[How does a zip file detect a correct password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199545/how-does-a-zip-file-detect-a-correct-password)

In the answer of this question, it said CRC is used to check if a password is correct. It also paste a code snippet from Info-zip to prove this.

However, after carefully studying the Info-zip source code, as below:

```
    if ((ush)(c | (b<<8)) != (GLOBAL(pInfo->ExtLocHdr) ?
                           ((ush)GLOBAL(lrec.last_mod_dos_datetime) & 0xffff) :
                           (ush)(GLOBAL(lrec.crc32) >> 16)))
```

I find when there is ExtLocHdr in the zip item, the lower 2 bytes of last_mod_dos_datetime, instead of the CRC, will be used to verify the password. But this is not mentioned in the file format specification in https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT at all.

Why?

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with security. This is either a coding question or a reverse engineering question. This is a "how does this program work?" question. You might want to use the answer to make your own bruteforcer, but that doesn't make this a security question.

Comment: @schroeder, Thank you. I ask in security site since the post I mentioned is also posted on security site, i.e., https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199545/how-does-a-zip-file-detect-a-correct-password